# Mostrar respuesta de un procemiento almacenado, convocado con laravel, en formato json

Tags: laravel, sql-server

tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado en sql server que me devuelve un mensaje de error en caso de que haya un registro duplicado

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ingresarusuario]
    @apellido varchar (50)=null,
    @nombre varchar (50)=null,
    @nombreusuario varchar (50)=null,
    @contraseña varchar(50)=null,
    @email varchar(50)=null,
    @tipo int=null, 
    @error varchar(8000)=null output
AS
BEGIN

    if ((select Count(*) as Total from USUARIO where login=@nombreusuario)=0)
    begin

            Insert into USUARIO (apellido, nombre, login, clave, email, tipo, estado) values (@apellido, @nombre, @nombreusuario, @contraseña, @email, @tipo, 0)
            select top 1 @error=idusuario from USUARIO order by idusuario desc
        
    END
    else
    BEGIN
        set @error= 'Ya existe un usuario con el nombre' + @nombreusuario
    END

    select @error as resultado

end
```

aqui tengo mi funcion store en mi controlador que lo que hace es enviar los datos al procedimiento almacenado en sqlserver y mostrar el mensaje que este regresa:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $apellido             =   $request->apellido;
        $nombre        =   $request->nombre;
        $nombreusuario             =   $request->nombreusuario;
        $contraseña      =   $request->contraseña;
        $email    =   $request->email;
        $tipo        = intval( $request->tipo ) ;

        $apellido        =   ($apellido   ==  NULL) ? ($apellido   =   '') :   $apellido;
        $nombre             =   ($nombre   ==  NULL) ? ($nombre   =   '') :   $nombre;
        $nombreusuario      =   ($nombreusuario   ==  NULL) ? ($nombreusuario   =   '') :   $nombreusuario;
        $contraseña    =   ($contraseña   ==  NULL) ? ($contraseña   =   '') :   $contraseña;
        $email        =   ($email   ==  NULL) ? ($email   =   '') :   $email;
        $tipo       =   ($tipo   ==  NULL) ? ($tipo   =   0) :   $tipo;
    
    
        $data = DB::insert("EXEC ingresarusuario '$apellido', '$nombre', '$nombreusuario', 
                                                    '$contraseña', '$email', '$tipo'");
    


        return $data;
```

sin embargo cuando ejecuto la consulta en postman me devuelve un valor numerico en lugar de mostrarme el mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor alguien podria decirme que estoy haciendo mal?